# Gstreamer: uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, embedded-linux, gstreamer-1.0, imx6

- iwave-g27s board.
- I.MX8 processor( sorry for imx6 tag on issue. There was no imx8)
- cat /etc/os-release

  ```
  ID="fsl-imx-xwayland"
  NAME="NXP i.MX Release"
  VERSION="L4.14.98-2.0.0_GA (sumo)"
  VERSION_ID="l4.14.98-2.0.0_ga"
  PRETTY_NAME="NXP i.MX Release L4.14.98-2.0.0_GA (sumo)"
  ```
- See3CAM_30 Camera

The problem i face is about gstreamer video resolation.
when i run;

```
root@iWave-G27S:~# gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 \                                                          
>  ! video/x-raw, width=1152, height=768, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert \
>  ! autovideosink
```

this problem accur and video stream freezes(only takes 1 frame to display);

```
[ 2991.335232] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.
```

The detailed ss;
[image]

i am saying its about resolution because when i decrease the resolution  there is no problem.
this works perfectly fine;

```
root@iWave-G27S:~# gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 \                                                          
>  ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert \
>  ! autovideosink
```